# Bootstrap Column Gap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add a gap between each column. If I add a margin property the columns do not fit in one row. How could I achieve 4 columns each row with gaps?

```
<style>
.test {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid test">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 test m-2">
                Hello
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 test m-2">
                Hello
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 test m-2">
                Hello
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 test m-2">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpkEj.png)

**EDIT:**
I think I overlook something ...
This works fine:

```css
.gap {
      margin: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: fit-content;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .row {
      display: flex;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Startseite</title>

    <!-- Basic Icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletest.css">
  
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 4
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

but if I add the latest bootstrap reference it does not work.
Like this:

```
.gap {
margin: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
width: fit-content;
padding: 10px;
}

.row {
display: flex;
border: 1px solid black;
}
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Startseite</title>

    <!-- Basic Icons-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletest.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 4
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 gap">
                columns 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```css
.background {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12 background">
        <h1>test1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12 background">
        <h1>test2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-12 background">
        <h1>test3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/justmemaarten/pen/mgYOGV

Answer (score 1):

Margins are essential to [how the grid columns work](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/). Instead adjust the *padding* to effect the space around the content of the columns...

https://codeply.com/go/YySEuVELp6

```
 <div class="container-fluid test">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 p-2">
            <div class="test">Hello</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 p-2">
            <div class="test">Hello</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 p-2">
            <div class="test">Hello</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 p-2">
           <div class="test">Hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: The space between columns is known as the "gutter".